# Regex for matching incorrect AND OR logic

Tags: regex, booleanquery

I need a regex that can match on an incorrect `AND` / `OR` logic statements but not if they are in quotes for example:

No matches should be found in:

```
MAR AND SATURN
MAR OR SATURN
"MAR AND SATURN"
```

There won't be any matches if `AND` or `OR` have at least 1 white space character plus 1 non-white space character on both sides and the characters are not made up of `OR` or `AND`. So for example  ..R AND S.. should not match but `(OR) OR (OR)` or `(AND) AND (AND)` should.

### Matches

```
  MARS AND SATURN [AND]
  MARS [OR]
  MARS [ OR ]
  [AND] AND [AND]
  [OR] [AND]
  [OR] [AND]
  [AND] [OR]
  [ AND ] [ OR ]
```

You will notice some examples contain white spaces before, after or on both sides of the `AND` or `OR` operator, these also need to match.

I'm using the .NET framework and this is what I came up with which works. However, it seems too complicated! There has to be a way to simplify it.

```
(?!.*\"")(?<!(?:\bAND\b\s|\bOR\b\s))(?:\b(?:AND|OR)\b)(?=\s\b(?:AND|OR)\b)|(?<=\bAND\b\s|\bOR\b\s)(?:\b(?:AND|OR)\b)(?!\s\b(?:AND|OR)\b)|^\b(?:AND|OR)\b|(?:AND\s?|OR\s?)$|(?<=\()\s?(?:\bAND\b|\bOR\b)|(?<=\()(?:\bOR|\bAND)(?=\))|(?:\bOR|\bAND)(?=\))(?!.*\"")
```

Comment: Could you please format the input text appropriately and specify where/what should be matched? I reformatted the beginning.

Comment: Your first example isn't an example of the sentence it follows :-/

Comment: So, you want to match all cases where `AND` or `OR` appear as the first or last term? What if there is no `AND` or `OR` at all?

Comment: @Aaron Thanks I've explained in a bit more detail what I mean, when I wrote 1 non-whitespace character on either side I meant including the white space that precedes it.

Comment: @tobias_k Not necessarily, you could have MARS AND SATURN OR OR PLUTO AND VENUS, in this instance the first OR should match as it is mismatched, the left hand side proposition proves true but not the left hand side.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So close! However it also should match on (AND) AND (AND) or (OR) OR (OR) - the brackets are not literal just an indicator of a match, please see my updated question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed your solution makes use of a negative lookahead  that specifies a word boundary that doesn't follow a non white space character and a space however it also needs to match on MARS [ OR ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do:

```
^ *'[^']*' *$|^ *"[^"]*" *$|(\b(AND|OR)\b) +(?1)|(?1)\s*$|^\s*(?1)
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/nD9yR3/2

### Explanation:

**This regex is to match the wrong string!!!**

1. `(?1)` is for recursive regex. It repeats regex of group 1.
2. `^ *'[^']*' *$|^ *"[^"]*" *$|` is for ignoring string inside quotes. It's considered a match if it has value for group 1, not group zero.

Comment: Doesn't `\S\b(AND...` mean that there is _no_ space between the words?

Comment: This regex is meant to find the wrong one. I've added a demo to proof it's right

Comment: The demo only proves that it's right w.r.t. your interpretation of the question. I don't think those `[`, `]` and `(whitespace)` parts are meant literally...

Comment: Hmmm,, then I need further explanation from the asker

Comment: .NET regex does not support recursive patterns.

Comment: regex101 does not support .NET regex.

Comment: @AminahNuraini This is brilliant, thank you! The back reference option is awesome! :-)

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad the recursive regex works in .NET eventually